# Can you prepare spells during Time Stop?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

[This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/161365/53359) brings up the terrifying idea of Persistent Time Stop. Upon reading this, my first thought was to cast it as a Wizard, rest fully, prepare all of my spells (including Persistent Time Stop) again, and then cast it again for an infinite loop. Is this possible by RAW? I'm unsure if the "apparent time" mentioned in the spell text would be enough to allow the user to prepare spells.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes, that's possible

A caster that casts the 9th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*time stop*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsTtoZ.html#time-stop) [trans] (*Player's Handbook* 294) modified with the metamagic feat Persistent Spell (*Complete Arcane* 81) can rest then prepare spells while in the spell's "apparent time." That is, while under the spell's effect the caster can't interact meaningfully with other creatures or objects they attend, the caster *can* still do pretty much anything else, including, presumably, resting and preparing spells normally.

Thus, for the small price of what is, effectively, a 15th-level spell and a few feats, a caster can have free reign of the multiverse—absent any creatures and their attended objects, of course. That caster will likely enjoy limitless wealth and power until his death by fiery, freezing, or fuming misadventure; old age; or another powerful creature in an area of antimagic. (And given the caster's likely power, that death may take awhile.)

---

***Note:*** The quaruts from the Fiend Folio *(102) are the [inevitables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inevitable_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)) that try to handle problems like this. I mean, I don't know what they'd do about it, exactly, but it is their job.*

Comment: Note that only wizards can prepare spells. Time-domain clerics need sunrise/sunset still.

Comment: Wich means if they cast it exactly at sunrise/sunset, midnight whatever, it should be fine right? nothing says it has to be a ''new sunrise'' is this correct?

Comment: And how do you persist a level 9 spell for a mage/sorcerer (assuming pre-epic)? Divine Metamagic it's easy with burning turn attemps. I see no sudden persistent spell feat I see no rod with the persistent ability, even the incantrix Instant Metamagic feature does not permit you to do it if the slot is higher than one you could cast. incantrix gives-1, practical metamagic -1, easy metamagic -1, arcane thesis -1, invisible spell -1 (with thesis) (some DM refuse this), (no energy type so energy substitution can't be used) the spell still is lvl 10. Cooperative Metamagic works but not for a loop.

Comment: Forceful Magic(3.0 not 3.5 though  Dragon #308) can make it work, and other metamagic +0  (if the DM accepts it works with arcane thesis to make -1)

Comment: Bard 10/Sublime Chord 9 with Metamagic Song  can do this I've read too. but how does a Wizard does so? ''Is this possible by RAW?'' is written in the description of the question, so I if anyone could post an answer about this or edit his answer that would be nice, I don't think another question should be written since it's written in the description. @KRyan, should I post another question? Should Hey I Can Chan edit his answer instead?

Comment: @MaximeCuillerier I think that *What's the least resource-intensive way for a wizard to cast a persistent* time stop *spell?* is a perfectly good standalone followup question.

Answer (score 0):

By very strict RAW, yes.  *Time stop* has a duration, so can be made persistent.  Eight hours passing for you is enough to refresh spells.  If you have a way to apply Persistent to a 9th level spell at least once per day, you can, in a GM-less environment  where only exact RAW applies, obliterate everything and everyone to your heart's content, or at least until whatever computer is running your game finishes searching the Monster Manuals for an Outsider or something that enforces time and can enter your *time stop* to stop you.